# How to convert CSV file with coordinates to rectangles (geometry) in FME

Tags: fme-form, smallworld-gis

Given four coordinates in csv file representing a coordinate system like this:

[image]

How can I use data from the table to create rectangle dataset using [FME](http://www.safe.com/). The dataset should have one feature per line in the csv-file.

Comment: Can you show your FME workspace as it is now? Which transformers have you tried? Why didn't they work?

Comment: It would also be useful to get an example of the CSV structure (eg x,y,x,y is one line?) but I'll make a guess at a solution below anyway.

Answer (score 6):

OK, I'm assuming your source CSV is a format like:

```
x1,y1,x2,y2
0,0,10,10
15,15,20,25
```

So, here you'll use the CSV reader to read the data.

The parameters dialog allows you to pick a column to use as an X and Y coordinate. DO NOT DO THAT! It won't use two columns and setting only one is not going to help.

So, once you have the CSV reader added, simply use a 2DBoxReplacer transformer. Select x1,y1 as the minimum coordinates, x2,y2 as the maximum.

The workspace will look like this:

[image]

I also put together a short movie demo at: http://screencast.com/t/dKfXTKkJ7Ell

Comment: Nice! I messed around with VertexCreator trying to sort and sample them before using pointConnector and AreaBuilder - and it failed :-)